# Deserialize JSON with Jackson with field dependency

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

In our project we parse JSON with Jackson. We set field `saved` by field `channelId`. Problem is that `channelId` field is parsed later than `saved`. So at the time we want to set field `saved` field `channelId` is null. How we can set field dependency in JSON deserialization, so field `saved` will be set after `channelId`?

This is part of our JSON data:

```
"message":{  
            "data":{  
               "text":"Some text"
            },
            "saved_by":[  
               2715,
               1234
            ],
            "some_boolean_field":false,
            "channel_id":8162
           }
```

This is our entity class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@org.parceler.Parcel(org.parceler.Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)

public class Message {

    @JsonProperty("channel_id")
    protected long channelId;

    protected boolean saved;

    @JsonSetter("saved_by")
    public void setSavedBy(Set<Long> savedBy) {
        saved = savedBy.contains(getUserIdByChannelId(channelId));
    }

    public long getChannelId() {
        return channelId;
    }

    public void setChannelId(long channelId) {
        this.channelId = channelId;
    }

    public boolean isSaved() {
        return saved;
    }

    public void setSaved(boolean saved) {
        this.saved = saved;
    }

    public void setData(JsonNode data) throws JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode textNode = data.get("text");
        text = textNode != null ? textNode.asText() : "";

        components = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonNode mediaNode = data.get("media");
        if (mediaNode != null) {
            MessageComponent[] parsedComponents = AppSession.getInstance().getObjectMapper().treeToValue(mediaNode, MessageComponent[].class);
            List<MessageComponent> components = Arrays.asList(parsedComponents).subList(0, parsedComponents.length < 4 ? parsedComponents.length : 4);

            this.components.addAll(components);
        }

        mediaCount = components.size();
    }

    }
```

Full JSON:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "serial":66,
      "updated_entity":"bookmark",
      "bookmark":{  
         "message":{  
            "data":{  
               "text":"hello"
            },
            "counted_serial":748,
            "saved_by":[  
               26526,
               27758
            ],
            "type":"UserMessage",
            "is_reviewed":false,
            "channel_id":8128,
            "id":2841531,
            "replied_message_data":null,
            "is_blocked":false,
            "is_deleted":false,
            "updated_at":"2016-11-21T05:59:52.471Z",
            "spam_reported_by":[  

            ],
            "created_at":"2016-11-19T15:40:17.027Z",
            "uuid":"0b6ba58e-f5e1-4ee5-a9da-041dfc2c85cd",
            "liked_by":[  

            ],
            "user":{  
               "last_name":"M",
               "id":4537,
               "first_name":"John",
               "is_deleted":false,
               "avatar_thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.site.org\/uploads\/99ef4d68-6eaf-4ba6-aafa-74d1cf895d71\/thumb.jpg"
            },
            "serial":934
         },
         "id":6931,
         "created_at":"2016-11-21T05:59:52.459Z",
         "is_deleted":false,
         "updated_at":"2016-11-21T05:59:52.459Z"
      }
   },
   "type":"action_performed"
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to reconstruct this from a constructor rather than by setting fields?

Comment: If the field `saved` is **always** dependent on `channelId` then why not set the field `saved` in `setChannelId()`?

Comment: JSON order is not guaranteed. For example in some phones I got correct field order, in other phones order is different.

Comment: In `setChannelId` we may not have `saved_by` values yet.

Comment: show complete json file...

Comment: Added full JSON file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hackish, but by making the `Message` class its own deserialization-builder, you get a kind of "ready for bean creation"-event in which you have access to all of the properties.

My suggestion is that you try the following :

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Message.class)
public class Message {

    ...

    @JsonSetter("saved_by")
    public void setSavedBy(Set<Long> savedBy) {
        // Merely store the value for later use.
        this.savedBy = savedBy;
    }

    ...

    public Message build() {
        // Calculate value of "saved" field.
        this.saved = this.savedBy.contains(getUserIdByChannelId(this.channelId));
        return this;
    }

    // Handling the added challenge.
    @JsonProperty("data") 
    public void setData(JsonNode data) throws JsonProcessingException {
       ...
    }
}
```

The above takes advantage of the default settings of the `JsonPOJOBuilder` annotation, namely that the default value for `buildMethodName` is `build`.

Comment: I tried your code, but object not setting all fields. Do I need to set all fields in `build()` method?

Comment: No, as long as there are setters, they ought to be used. Did you try setting a couple of breakpoints to see if they get hit?

Comment: I just re-ran my sandbox tests, and they definitely work. Are you seeing any errors? Are deserializing using like this: `Message message = om.readValue(json, Message.class);` ?

Comment: Yes we deserialize like this. I added `setData()` method that we have in this class which is causing the problem when I added  your method `build().` After adding method `build()' it not get called anymore, but without `build()' its called. We use it to set multiple parameters from `data` field in JSON

Comment: Adding `@JsonProperty("data")` to the method seemed to solve the problem you added. Please try that.